# string slicing, Search a character

Tags: python, python-3.x

i was able to figure out the problem! thank you all for your comments and suggestions and COACHING :).

This is my final result and it works just fine:

print("Hello, and welcome! What is first and last name?")

name = input()
print("There are", len(name), "letters in your name.")

print("What letter would you like to search for in your name?")

letter = input()

print("What letter would you like to search for in your name?")

letter = input()

if letter.lower:

find_letter = name.find(letter)

```
print(find_letter+1)
```

if letter.upper:

```
find_letter = name.find(letter)

print(find_letter+1)
```

Hopefully this appears neat in my submission, haven't figured out how to make it look like code when i submit it yet... i think it auto corrects it if it recognizes code

Comment: Do you want to find the first occurrence of the letter or all occurrences?

Comment: It was to find all the occurrences, but received great help :)

Comment: Alright, if you want to find all the occurrences, `str.find` is not a good approach. It will only find the first occurrence, and using it to find all occurrences by consecutively slicing the sting will get ugly.

Comment: I should clarify, All occurrences of a single letter. But i was able to solve the matter. Thank you :)

Comment: "All occurrences of a single letter". <- Yes, that's what I meant. Now if you search for 'o' in "John Doe" with `str.find`, it will only find the first occurrence.

Comment: but if you us print(str.find+1) then it will keep on going until it finds all :)

Comment: dang, but with this one, if letter:
    find_letter = name.find(letter)
    print(find_letter+1), it worked. That is what i am using as my code and it was able to find the o in John Doe and it returned the results of 2

Comment: The result 2 tells you that the first 'o' is at character 2 of your string. It did not find the second 'o' at character number 7. Try the name "John Doe Schmo". Your current solution returns 2 for this name as well.

Comment: So could it be that you just want to *count* a character, and not actually *search* for it? If that's the case, `str.find` is not doing what you are expecting it to do, either. I have added an example to my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean but how about this?

```
print("Hello, and welcome! What is first and last name?")
name = input()
print("There are", len(name), "letters in your name.")
print("What letter would you like to search for in your name?")
letter = input()
if letter:
    find_letter = name.find(letter)
    print(find_letter+1)
```

Comment: It's confusing to explain lol, but i will take an attempt at that!

Comment: Perfect! That is what i was attempting to go for... i forgot about the if statement... The assignment part was the following: First, ask the user to enter their name, first and last.,  Then Ask the user to enter a letter that they would like to find in their name. Count how many times that letter occurs in their name, and print out the count. (Be sure to count both lowercase and uppercase instances of the letter)

Comment: Question, now why would it be just " if letter: " ? shouldn't there be more added to that like < > or =?

Comment: I figured it out and it makes sense to me now! "If the letter: is in the name, then find the letter... "something along those lines, but it makes sense now in my head!

Answer (score 1):

`str.find` will only give you the index of the first occurrence of the character, for example:

```
>>> s = 'hello'
>>> s.find('l')
2
```

In order to find all the occurrences, it is best to enumerate the string and remember the indices of the characters that match the search character.

Demo:

```
>>> name = input('input a name: ')
input a name: John Doe
>>> find_me = input('input character to search for: ')
input character to search for: o
>>> [index for index, char in enumerate(name) if char == find_me]
[1, 6]
```

The result list tells you that the character `'o'` can be found at index 1 and 6 of the name. If you want an offset (for example, start counting the indices at one, not at zero), specify it as the second argument to `enumerate`:

```
>>> [index for index, char in enumerate(name, 1) if char == find_me]
[2, 7]
```

The result list tells you that the letter `'o'` can be found at the second and seventh character of the name (if you start counting at 1).

edit:

From the discussion in the comments I have the feeling that you maybe just want to count a single letter.

Just use the string's `count` method for that:

```
>>> name = input('input a name: ')
input a name: John Doe Schmo
>>> find_me = input('input character to search for: ')
input character to search for: o
>>> name.count(find_me)
3
```